# Why I can't partition my drive in Ubuntu using gparted?

Tags: partitioning, 14.10, gparted, disk

My problem is that when attempting to resize the dev / sda2, both the minimum and the maximum size, are of the same value (which is the disk size: 708 862 MB).

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1B9q3LPE15I/VZmIPPiXU2I/AAAAAAAABSM/ugGbYf9SXo0/s1600/Captura%2Bde%2Btela%2Bde%2B2015-07-05%2B16%253A40%253A17.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not resize partitions because they are locked.

You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB to do it.

It is impossible to resize Ubuntu partitions from inside a working system.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the active OS to alter the media that hosts the active OS. It's like you doing brain surgery on yourself. You need to boot to an OS hosted on different media. A live-booting version of Ubuntu on a USB flash drive would be excellent, but **back up everything you don't want to lose first!**